# Impala joining and converting string columns to create date

Tags: impala

I have a data set which has three columns in string format.

Year: YYYY
Date: DD
Month: A string from 1 to 12.

I need help joining and converting this to a single date as YYYY-MM-DD. Appreciate  any help / guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CONCAT_WS function as shown below and then cast the string to timestamp if you so desire:

```
 SELECT  
CAST(CONCAT_WS("-", year_column, month_column, day_column) AS timestamp) AS full_date FROM a_database.a_table
```